# Insert the succeeded word before conjunction 'and' using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-group, python-re

**Input String**:

> However, the gene of hBD-1 and LL-27 expression was not affected by cancer in both acne and non-acne patients.

**Expected Output String**:

> However, the gene of hBD-1 expression and LL-27 expression was not affected by cancer in both acne patients and non-acne patients.

**Code:**

```py
import re
string_a = "However, the gene of hBD-1 and LL-27 expression was not affected by cancer in both acne and non-acne patients."
print(string_a)
print('\n')
output = re.sub(r'\b(\w+-(\d+|[A-Za-z]+))\b(?! [A-Za-z]+\b)', r'\b(\1 [A-Za-z]+)\b', string_a)
print(output)
```

I am not getting the exact output string. Please look into my code and suggest or modify the solution.

Comment: If your real problem be different or more extended than what you posted above, then please _edit_ your question and include more information.

Comment: Tim, I have edited it. Please check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `re.sub` here to selectively replace any gene term with itself followed by the text `expression`, for those genes who do not already have this text following it.

```py
inp = "However, the gene of hBD-1 and LL-27 expression was not affected by acnes."
output = re.sub(r'\b(\w+-\d+)\b(?! expression\b)', r'\1 expression', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
However, the gene of hBD-1 expression and LL-27 expression was not affected by acnes.
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the solution is not dynamic. I have tried the generic way in this but it won't work. Will you please try for the generic case.
re.sub(r'\b(\w+-\d+)\b(?! [A-Za-z]+\b)', r'\1 [A-Za-z]+')

Comment: If you want something more specific than the answer I gave here, you will have to tell us the rules for identifying gene abbreviations.

Comment: Tim thank you for your response. I agree with you but we are doing it for NER so no need to consider the rules. You can try your regex on this.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, therefore my answer doesn't change.